# Update document library folder when SharePoint list attachment is modified/updated

Tags: list, power-automate, flow, attachments

I have a SharePoint list. The list contains separate rows of issues. Each issue requires attachment upload from the respective person. There is a separate document library mapped for each issue.

How to create a flow such that:

- When a person uploads their attachment (modifies the attachment column), Power automate is triggered and updates the corresponding document library folder for the SharePoint list item (modified).